# Apache2 Reverse Proxy, why does my solution never match the example?

Tags: grails, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, apache2.2

I need to make a reverse proxy back to a tomcat server running a grails application.
I have always seen reverse proxy examples like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

In all my apps though, when I do that the page comes up and my statics get loaded like this with the context:
**/appname/static/[jsapp.js][mycss.css]**

so consequently styling and functionality are lost.  So my workaround is has been to do this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /appname/ http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPassReverse /appname/ http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/appname/
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

which I guess is a reverse-reverse-proxy; either way it seems hacky and has (what i think is) a side affect; it creates the URL with the tomcat context in it: http://servername.com/appname/user/username instead of http://servername.com/user/username. I would much prefer the later if its possible without losing the styling.

NOTES:

- When i go to the base URL:http://servername.com it works fine, any link i click on after that puts the "/appname/" name in the URL.
- I believe that I could resolve this by making the app on tomcat the ROOT app, however, I would prefer not to.
- This example is using HTTP, I normally use AJP protocol, but I tried HTTP last just for kicks
- This is in a NameVirtualHost configuration.
- Apache 2.2.15, Tomcat 7.0.27, CentOS release 6.2 (Final), java version "1.7.0_04", Grails 2.0.4

Any thoughts on what I need to be doing differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, how to solve this situation. I am using vhosts inside TomCat, so I eliminate the application name in the URL. Add this to your server.xml

```
<Host name="myapp.com"  appBase="myappbase" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
    <Alias>www.myapp.com</Alias>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="myapp_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Context path="/thumbnails" docBase="/var/www/myapp/thumbnails" reloadable="true">

</Host>
```

in your $TOMCAT_HOME create a directory "myappbase", where you upload your application WAR as ROOT.war. Your application is available via http://myapp.com:8080/.

Your proxy configuration is than very simple ;-) You can also make more vhosts in 1 TomCat.

In the aforementioned configration is also an directory alias (thumbnails), which is accessible via http://myapp.com/thumbnails/ and you can use it in GSP via:

```
${ resource( dir: 'thumbnails', file: 'image01.png' ) }
```

And the last point, which can help you is setting a "static" directories in UrlMappings.groovy. These directories are ignored when translation URL to controllers and vice versa:

```
static excludes = [
        '/css*', '/js*', '/thumbnails*'
]
```

Comment: very nice, i'm going to give this a shot in a little bit.  However if i have one server with tomcat on 8080 and httpd on 80, i guess i'm going to need the additional step of editing the host file so the reverse proxy knows where myapp is because localhost:8080 isn't going to work anymore.  I will report back my results, thanks again.

Comment: You can change the attribute "name" in the "Host" to anything you need, which is then configurable in /etc/hosts and the proxy can reach.

Comment: so i have qas.1 as name, in /etc/hosts i have 127.0.0.1 qas.1 and have proxy configure like this: ProxyPass / http://qas.1:8080/  but its bringing up the tomcat localhost not my app.  I tried the alias name first with same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: i wasn't realizing it was just passing the entire name along, i was way over thinking it.  I got it now, thanks for the help.